# ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version

Tags: solidity, error, solc, brownie, compiler

I am a beginner working on brownie using vscode related to a lottery smart contract. Please don't mind if I am doing any rookie mistakes I am still trying my best to understand it as much as I can :) PROBLEM : The solidity compiler is set to remote and its version is 0.6.6 and even though the required solidity version in the source file is ^0.4.11 I am unable to get past the compilation and if I try to run `brownie run scripts/deployLottery.py` I am presented with the same error.

The .sol file is

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase {

    enum LOTTERY_STATE {
        OPEN,
        CLOSED,
        GET_WINNER
    }

    address private owner;
    address public winner;
    address payable[] public contestents;
    uint256 public fee;
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    bytes32 public requestID;
    bytes32 public keyHash;
    LOTTERY_STATE public ls;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _;
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner!");
        _;
    }

    constructor(
        address _priceFeed,
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        address _link,
        uint256 _fee,
        bytes32 _keyHash
    ) public VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _link) {

        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        ls = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        fee = _fee;
        keyHash = _keyHash;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function get_ethUsdPrice() private view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() private view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 answer = get_ethUsdPrice();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = answer * (10**10);
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * (10**18)) / adjustedPrice;

        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public onlyOwner {
        require(
            ls == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED,
            "Can't start another lottery before the previous one finishes!!"
        );
        ls = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
    }

    function enterLottery() public payable {
        require(
            ls == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN,
            "Lottery is unavailable/terminated. Try again later."
        );
        require(
            msg.value >= getEntranceFee(),
            "You need to send $50 Worth of eth!!"
        );
        contestents.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function endLottery() public onlyOwner {
        require(ls == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN, "The lottery is yet to start!!");

        ls = LOTTERY_STATE.GET_WINNER;
        requestID = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness)
        internal
        override
    {
        require(_requestId == requestID, "The Request IDs Don't Match!");
        require(ls == LOTTERY_STATE.GET_WINNER, "Can't Procceed!!");
        require(_randomness > 0, "Random Not Found!!!");

        uint256 winnerAdd = _randomness % contestents.length;
        winner = contestents[winnerAdd];
        payable(winner).transfer(address(this).balance);

        contestents = new address payable[](0);
        ls = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
    }
}
```

When I run `brownie compile` in the same folder it gives me

```
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.6
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

/home/botvenom/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.4/ERC677Token.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.6+commit.6c089d02.Linux.g++ - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
^----------------------^

/home/botvenom/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/StandardToken.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.6+commit.6c089d02.Linux.g++ - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
^----------------------^
```

In the config file

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1

compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

Which are set to the following in the settings.json

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/bin/python",
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.6.6",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "bracketPairColorizer.depreciation-notice": false,
    "solidity.remappings": [
        "@chainlink/=/home/botvenom/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1",
        "@openzeppelin/=/home/botvenom/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0"
    ]
}
```

This is the compiler details from the Lottery.json file

```
"compiler": {
    "evm_version": "istanbul",
    "optimizer": {
      "enabled": true,
      "runs": 200
    },
    "version": "0.6.6+commit.6c089d02"
  },
```

I tried to change the original pragma to `pragma solidity >=0.4.11;` in both the source files but it is leading to more errors like these to name a few

```
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.6
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

/home/botvenom/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/StandardToken.sol:56:56: ParserError: The state mutability modifier "constant" was removed in version 0.5.0. Use "view" or "pure" instead.
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
                                                       ^------^

/home/botvenom/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.4/interfaces/ERC677.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.6+commit.6c089d02.Linux.g++ - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
^---------------------^
```

Just to add at last, I copy pasted the exact code on Remix IDE too and there it is compiling successfully with no errors. I have been so confused about what to do, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is too much difference between versions 0.4.x and 0.6.x - most likely you will have to use the same version for your contract as in the imported files.

Comment: So if I degraded the compiler versions to 0.4.x in the contracts they might start running?

Comment: Try this :-) ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your truffle-config.js file:

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
        version: "pragma",//<-- this is the magic
        settings: {
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true,
                runs: 200
            }
        }
    }
}
```